# From a Sybase Database, how I can get database state ?

Tags: sap-ase

Anyone can explain , query for sybase database state ?

for this

am tried below query , but its not working..

select name from sysdatabases where status2='..'

Answer (score 0):

`status2` is an `smallint` datatype, so using quotes to find a value will give you a syntax error.  You need to specify either a number, or range of numbers (without quotes) to get the query to return.

```
select name from sysdatabases where status2 = 1
```

or

```
select name from sysdatabases where status2 in (0,1)
```

More information on **sysdatabases** can be found here:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/X42615.htm

Comment: status2='..' i represents 1,2,4,8,16 .. values only i have to conform if there any other quries is for find sybase state ?

Comment: `status` is also used to denote the database state.  I'm updating the my answer to include a link to the `sysdatabases` table information.